# swift if or/and statement like python

Tags: python, if-statement, swift

Is there a way to to do and/or in an if statement in swift. eg/

```
if a > 0 and i == j or f < 3:
    //do something
```

can we do that in swift?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use

---

```
&&
```

for logical and

---

```
||
```

for logical or

---

so you can do

```
if a > 0 && i == j || f < 3 {
    ...
}
```

see here
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

```
if (a > 0 && i == j || f < 3){
    //do something
}
```

You should probably do some reading on the [basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) of Swift before jumping in. If statements are covered in there.